# Elements with float: left directly below the above on new row

Tags: html, css, position, css-float, positioning

I'm trying to fill my screen with boxes so I've floated them *left*.

My problem is, that the boxes have different heights. So the when a new line begin, the top Position of the first Div is equal to the bottom position of the tallest.

Have anyone an idea, how i could fix that problem

It's difficult to explain, so I've made a screenshot.

http://s7.directupload.net/images/140506/rdzp72sh.jpg

greez!

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: i think you're looking for something like this : http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: you should some thing like a grid using css try googling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a jquery solution. Only from Css  you can not solve this.
A not paid version for "arrange" divs in optimal vertical position with different height in the layout is http://masonry.desandro.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this, it might help you.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/825/Pinterest-Style-Column-Layout-In-Pure-CSS